# How do I let clients edit the page if I created website using react and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, content-management-system

I have been learning to create websites and very new to react and rails and like the combination between the two so far. So I was wondering what would I have to do to let clients edit the page contents without any coding knowledge. I watched some CMS tutorial videos and saw people using wordpress to achieve this. But I think you would have to have written your website using PHP to use wordpress as a CMS right? Please correct me if I am mistaken. And please suggest any CMS for rails and react. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are a beginner; and while you do need PHP on your webserver to run WordPress, the setup will be a *lot* easier than a rails / react CMS. Of course you will learn loads in either case, but if you need something soon I would have another look into a simple hosting solution for WordPress (or similar).

Comment: sweet. thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at our Rails based CMS Scrivito: https://scrivito.com/ - which has also support for JS customiziation.